# Error -2147417848 (&H80010108): The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have a huge vba project with 10 complex userforms and with a lot of other functions and subs.
Then I have debug window open everything works perfectly and the next time I open the file it works also well, but if I open it 2nd or 3rd time (without opening debug window) I receive the following error:

> **Error -2147417848 (&H80010108): The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.**

After few hours I found the source of this error, once I exclude the following line it works perfectly:

```
ws.Cells(nr + 5, 7) = Me.tb_COT_MP_SM.Value
```

This code transfers value from one of the textboxes of main big userform to cell. I read the [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319832) related to this error and tried to Dim this textbox as an MSForms object but it didn't help..

Thank you in advance for any support.

Comment: If it transfer data from cells to textbox then textbox should come first (before equal).Like .. `Me.tb_COT_MP_SM=ws.Cells(nr + 5, 7)` Try also removing `.value` from `Me.tb_COT_MP_SM.Value`

Comment: @harun24hr sorry, it's opposite.. I tried removing value, thanks for this advice.

Comment: Have you tried to change the "Me." to the actual object? For example: ActiveWorksheet. or Sheets("whatevername"). or whatever it is

Comment: @Kathara Yes, didn't help

Comment: What is me in this case if I may ask? And is nr like a counter? A little more code (above and below) might be helpful :)

Comment: another question: what kind of connection do you set up in this workbook?? Can you give us the code where you connect and deconnect? (change the values that should not be known......)

Comment: @Kathara me is the main userform on which the textbox is located

Comment: did you rename your userform? what kind of control do you get the value from?

Comment: @kathara no, within this userform I can use Me to refer to it

Comment: Ok, can you rename it once and then instead of the Me use the name? It might be better to do it this way as you have a lot of userforms as you said

Comment: @Kathara thank you, but it didn't help

Comment: OOOh are you working from Word or from Excel? Or rather is your userform also in excel?

Answer (score 0):

Something somewhere in your code has either unloaded or destroyed or not created either ws or me (probably ws)

Comment: I've already tried to change `Me.tb_COT_MP_SM.Value` with some text value and code was working. I will try to find missing ws, but I think the problem hides in right part of the equation

Comment: you could try replacing me. with the fully qualified name of the form

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work (but I don't know Why):

```
ws.Cells(nr + 5, 7).Value = CStr(Me.tb_COT_MP_SM.Value)
```